# Are differences between elements besides the number of valence electrons negligible in forming matter and giving certain properties?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, quantum-chemistry, elements

We were talking about life complexity, I don't know almost anything about physics, he told me that differences between elements beside the number of valence electrons are negligible and elements with the same valence electrons could be interchangable. My thought is that if there are 118 number of elements instead of 12-18 there is a reason and in talking about complexity/organization of life the differences are important.

This was the contest of the question more or less, but you can ignore the contest and just answer the question:

Are differences between elements besides the number of valence electrons negligible in forming matter and giving certain properties?

Comment: Well, oxygen and sulphur have the same number of valence electrons. I drink $H_2O$, but I would never drink $H_2S$ :)

Comment: Far too strongly stated, and while the question is more or less OK for physics it would have been a natural for [chemistry.se].

Comment: The most trivial reason is that the effective diameters of atoms are vastly different and much of chemistry is actually dominated by those diameters. Whether compounds can form and reactions can occur (especially in organic chemistry) can often be predicted by geometric considerations.

Answer (score 0):

The central charge of atoms also strongly influences it's chemical actions. For example, ionization energies change with both the number of central positives.

With regards to quantum mechanics, the Born - Oppenheimer approximation is used for calculating bond lengths, and depends on both the state of the nucleus as well as the state of the electron cloud, so clearly this too would be an influence.

The devil is in the details.